# open bank problem, cant seem to figure out why my solution isnt passing one last test case

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am trying to solve a problem on DoSelect Platform..

Following is the problem statement

Sid, as a developer wants to contribute to the Open Bank Project. He wants to create functions for deposit money, withdraw money, add interest and apply bank charges (in some cases) for a bank account.

There is also a constraint of this type of account, that any time if an operation causes the account balance to be negative, the account balance is reinitialised with 100. For example, if the current balance is 40 and you want to withdraw 60, then as 40-60 is negative, after this operation, now the account has 100.

As he thinks himself a smart coder, he wants to create a single function for all these tasks. The function is "Transaction" and it takes at most two parameters "a" and "b". Based on which parameter(s) is given, it performs different tasks. But Sid has no idea about OOP concepts.

```py
class Account:
      function init (variable balance):
          //init is the standerd python __init__(self, variables) method. 
          //it initializes the account with user given balance 
          member variable balance= balance 
 
      function transaction (variable a, variable b):
          //a (if given) denotes the amount to be withdraw/deposit in the account. 
              //so add a to balance if a is positive, otherwise subtract (-a) from balance if a is negative.
          //b (if given) denotes the interest rate to give/charge to the account based on its sign.
              //so add b% of current balance (rounded to nearest integer) to the balance as an interest, if b is positive 
          //otherwise subtract (-b)% of currenct balance (rounded to nearest integer) to the balance as bank charge, if b is negative
          //after each operation, take care that, any time balance goes to negative, make it as 100. 
 
          //if neither a nor b is given:
              //do nothing
          //if a is given but b is not given:
              //add/subtract a to the balance, based on sign of a
          //if a is not given and b is given:
              //add/subtract b% of current balance to the balance, based on sign of b
          //if both a and b are given:
              //first add/subtract a to the balance, get the new balance, then add/subtract b% of the new balance to the new balance.
          //everytime take care that, if balance goes to negative, reinitialize it with 100.
```

Following is what I did

```
class Account:
    
    def __init__(self, balance):
        self.balance = balance
        #self.balance = 100
    
    def transaction(self, a = 0, b = 0):
        if a != 0 and b != 0:
            self.balance += a
            self.balance += round((self.balance) * (b / 100))
            if self.balance < 0:
                self.balance = 100
        elif a != 0 and b == 0:
            self.balance += a
            if self.balance < 0:
                self.balance = 100
        elif a==0 and b != 0:
            self.balance += round((self.balance) * (b / 100))
            if self.balance < 0:
                self.balance = 100
        else:
            pass
        return self.balance
    
    def get_balance(self):
        return self.balance
```

When I verify on the platform, it successfully verifies on the test case. However, when I try to submit it, it fails on 1 test case. DoSelect platform don't show what test cases they used to verify, so I cant figure it out.

Comment: `Account(0).transaction(-1, 10)` gives `100` with your solution. The task says to reinitialize the balance to 100 every time it goes to negative. If you apply this rule to every single step the result should be `110` (`0` -> `-1` -> `100` -> `110`).

Comment: The thing I see is that `if both a and b are given: [...] everytime take care that, if balance goes to negative, reinitialize it with 100` is not respected in the code.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment: `Account(0).transaction(-1, 10)` gives `100` with your solution. The task says to reinitialize the balance to `100` every time it goes to negative. If you apply this rule to every single step, the result should be `110` (0 -> -1 -> 100 -> 110).

I don't see the need for the different if-combinations for `a` and `b`. This is the moment when a developer has to translate the requirements into meaningful code. And the method `get_balance` is not needed, you can access the attribute directly.

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, balance):
        self.balance = balance
        if self.balance < 0:
            self.balance = 100

    def transaction(self, a=0, b=0):
        self.balance += a
        if self.balance < 0:
            self.balance = 100
        self.balance += round(self.balance * (b / 100))
        if self.balance < 0:
            self.balance = 100


account = Account(0)
account.transaction(-1, 10)
print(account.balance)
```

A "normal" programmer would create a method for the handling of `if self.balance < 0`, but since *Sid has no idea about OOP concepts* I just duplicated the code. With OOP the code for the class could be:

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, balance):
        self.balance = balance
        self.adjust_balance()

    def adjust_balance(self):
        if self.balance < 0:
            self.balance = 100

    def transaction(self, a=0, b=0):
        self.balance += a
        self.adjust_balance()
        self.balance += round(self.balance * (b / 100))
        self.adjust_balance()
```

With some more experience a programmer might use a property for the balance.

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, balance):
        self._balance = balance

    @property
    def balance(self):
        return self._balance

    @balance.setter
    def balance(self, value):
        self._balance = value
        if self._balance < 0:
            self._balance = 100

    def transaction(self, a=0, b=0):
        self.balance += a
        self.balance += round(self.balance * (b / 100))
```

Comment: To my supprise, it still doesnt accepts this solution! Fails the same test which my code was failing..

Comment: You can go to DoSelect website and search for "Open Bank Project"..